# Вывод окна Pyqt5 без консоли на windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

Что мне нужно добавить в код, чтобы окно консоли не открывалось вместе с GUI? Видел что советуют поменять формат исполняемого файла или что-то прописывать в PATH, но мне такое не подходит. Я знаю что это можно прописать в коде, где-то на стадии инициализации класса, но я не помню как (заметки утеряны).

Comment: просто запускайте не python а pythonw

Comment: pythonw файл.py? Нет, запуск должен производится по клику мыши, а не через терминал.